# FQL query for future events created by a page/user failing unexpectedly?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I have an FQL query which my site has used to pull various user or page's active events, and display them on a map. This has worked well for the last year.

```
SELECT eid, update_time
FROM event
WHERE creator = 139074072804205 
    AND (end_time >= now() OR (end_time = 'null' AND start_time >= now()))
    AND eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 139074072804205)
```

However, sometime in the last 2 months the query has stopped working, and returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
  "type": "OAuthException", 
  "code": 1
  }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on? The page I'm querying in the example above is public, and has at least 6 public events.

https://www.facebook.com/USCSEATTLE/events

The only quirk I've noticed is that if I remove the `creator = 139074072804205` condition in the `WHERE` clause, the query returns results... but of course it returns all future events the the page has RSVP'd to rather than the ones the page created.

**EDIT:**

Seems this is a known bug since March 2013.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/501594683237232